# Not able to fully download Timeshift in Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

Tags: 18.04

New to Ubuntu . 
Tried to download TIMESHIFT in Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
First two commands into Terminal  seem OK .
On third command this shows: 
p

```
at@pat-MS-7800:~$ sudo apt-get install timeshift
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
timeshift is already the newest version (19.08.1-0~201908111351~ubuntu18.04.1).
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 4 not to upgrade.
pat@pat-MS-7800:~$
```

Where to go from here - is the question ?

Comment: It is already installed. What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Timeshift is already installed. Now go ahead and use it.

Comment: Hi there .  Apologies .. but it is not listed anywhere in Ubuntu Software .

Comment: Apologies again . Many thanks for your help. Just FOUND IT.